# Store complex data structure (JSON Array) in Redis

Tags: redis

I have a chat app and I'd like to store recent conversations in Redis. My idea is to have something like this:

```
{
      “userB” : {
      “userAvatar” : "someURL",
      "lastMessage" : "Hi"
    },

      “userC” : {
      “userAvatar” : "someURL",
      "lastMessage" : "Hi"
    },

      “userD” : {
      “userAvatar” : "someURL",
      "lastMessage" : "Hi"
    }

}
```

So lets say that `userA` had chat with `userB`, `userC`, and `userD`.

Can I somehow store this in hash with the key as `userA`... (`HSET userA`) But how can I store array type of values inside it? And is it possible to update the content inside this array? For example if userA and userB have further conversation. How can I keep the `lastMessage` always updated?

Comment: last message supposes to be between 2 users right? if so can you store it in a key like `lastmsg:userA:userB`. that way, you only have a single source of truth to get last msg

Comment: Yes. But i need other details like userAvatar, date, etc. And also I don't know ids of userB, userC and userD in this case. That's why I want to keep it in Hash or something like that in order that userA (which id I know) have ids (of userB, userC and userD) and other data.

Comment: @harunB10 did you consider using the RedisJSON module?

Comment: Will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @harunB10 Beside RedisJSON, you can also try [redis-protobuf](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-protobuf) module, which supports nested data structures.